# How to do advanced SQL join predicates/tips to avoid undesired rows?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

This first part is a description of the real world situation I am dealing with building a report on inventory swaps where I have separated tables of reports linked to assets, tables with details about the assets, and tables of RMA Requests, but no direct relation to which assset was replaced by other asset only a vague relationship of the RMA orders linked to reports orders.

I have four tables.

- table 1 represents reports of malfunctioning devices.
- table 2 is an inventory table full of devices details, etc.
- table 3 represents replacement orders.
- table 4 represents the orders-replacements relations.

So records are like this.

```
table 1 are something like.
orderNo -  reported item 
1               1
1               2
2              56
2              34
2              23
3              15

table 2 
device id    lots of device detailed stuff in columns.
1              ...
2              ...
3              ...
...
15
23
34
56

table 3 (replacements)
rmaid   replacement
1           3
1           4
2           7
2           8
2           9
3           16
```

This is an example of the problem I am trying to resolve, and where my question emerge.

```
create table report(
    ID  int  not null,
    itemID int );

    insert into report (ID, ItemID)
    values (1,1),(1,2),(2,56),(2,34),(2,23),(3,15)

    create table device(
    ID int not null,
    dev_detail nvarchar(50) 
    );

    insert into device (ID, dev_detail)
    values (1,'det1'),(2,'det2'),(3,'det3'),(4,'det4'),(5,'det5'),
        (6,'det6'),(7,'det7'),(8,'det8'),(9,'det9'),(15,'det15'),
        (16,'det16'),(23,'dev23'),(34,'det34'),(56,'det56')

    create table replacement(
    id  int not null,
    ItemID int );

    insert into replacement (ID, ItemID)
    values (1,3),(1,4),(2,7),(2,8),(2,9),(3,16)

    create table [report-replacement](
    ID int not null,
    reportID int,
    replaceID int);

    insert into [report-replacement] (ID, reportID, replaceID)
    values (1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3)

    select 
    rep.ID as report_id,
    rep.itemID as reported_item,
    rep.dev_detail as reported_item_detail,
    rep.replaceID as report_replace_id,
    rma.id as rma_id,
    rma.ItemID as rma_item,
    rma.dev_detail as rma_item_detail

    from
    (
      select report.ID,report.itemID,device.dev_detail, replaceID
      from 
       report 
        inner join device on report.itemID = device.ID
        inner join [report-replacement] on reportID = [report-replacement].reportID
    ) as Rep
    inner join
    (
      select 
      replacement.id,replacement.ItemID,device.dev_detail
      from 
      replacement 
      inner join device on replacement.ItemID = device.ID
    ) as RMA
    on Rep.replaceID = RMA.id

    drop table report, device,replacement,[report-replacement]
```

This is the desired output, I would like help to build a on predicate join for the main inner join so that I get a 1 to 1 ratio of reported items to replaced items:

```
report id, item id, item details, rma_id, rma_item, rma_item_detail
1           1           det1        1        3          det3
1           2           det2        1        4          det4
2           56          det56       2        7          det7
2           34          det34       2        8          det8
2           23          det23       2        9          det9
3           15          det15       3       16          det16
```

This is the result of execution the example code, problem is I am getting a lot of rows and I am only using inner joins. There shouldn't be that many, and my question is if there is pecial join predicate, some clever way to get the desired output.

```
report_id   reported_item   reported_item_detail    report_replace_id   rma_id  rma_item    rma_item_detail
    1           1               det1                    1               1       3           det3
    1           2               det2                    1               1       3           det3
    2           56              det56                   1               1       3           det3
    2           34              det34                   1               1       3           det3
    2           23              dev23                   1               1       3           det3
    3           15              det15                   1               1       3           det3
    1           1               det1                    1               1       4           det4
    1           2               det2                    1               1       4           det4
    2           56              det56                   1               1       4           det4
    2           34              det34                   1               1       4           det4
    2           23              dev23                   1               1       4           det4
    3           15              det15                   1               1       4           det4
    1           1               det1                    2               2       7           det7
    1           2               det2                    2               2       7           det7
    2           56              det56                   2               2       7           det7
    2           34              det34                   2               2       7           det7
    2           23              dev23                   2               2       7           det7
    3           15              det15                   2               2       7           det7
    1           1               det1                    2               2       8           det8
    1           2               det2                    2               2       8           det8
    2           56              det56                   2               2       8           det8
    2           34              det34                   2               2       8           det8
    2           23              dev23                   2               2       8           det8
    3           15              det15                   2               2       8           det8
    1           1               det1                    2               2       9           det9
    1           2               det2                    2               2       9           det9
    2           56              det56                   2               2       9           det9
    2           34              det34                   2               2       9           det9
    2           23              dev23                   2               2       9           det9
    3           15              det15                   2               2       9           det9
    1           1               det1                    3               3       16          det16
    1           2               det2                    3               3       16          det16
    2           56              det56                   3               3       16          det16
    2           34              det34                   3               3       16          det16
    2           23              dev23                   3               3       16          det16
    3           15              det15                   3               3       16          det16
```

It's multiplying every record of the orders with every record of the replacements, and it's supposed to do only inner joins of two tables that previously joins with the device for getting details, so as you can see 
every device number gets its device details (16 gets det16 ).

I found that both joins RMA and Reps are both ok when joining with the device detail table, but the inner join of table reports with table [report-replacement] was not working properly so I changed the on clause order from  reportID = [report-replacement].reportID to
[report-replacement].reportID = reportID, and that decreased the rows from 36 to 14 rows.

Comment: May I ask which RDBMS you are using? Oracle, MS SQL server or anything else?

Comment: When you added the SQL tag, a large suggestion was displayed that recommended you also add a tag for the specific DBMS you're using, as functionality and syntax varies between them. You chose to ignore that, which means we get to play the **What DBMS are you using?** game until you add a tag for it. **Please edit your post to add that tag now.** While you're making that [edit], you can also add a description of the problem you're having with the SQL you're using now, and ask a specific question related to that SQL. Thanks.

Comment: Gen Wan, Ken White, thanks for your suggestions, i have added the DBMS i am using, MSSQL server express 2016, i am looking for suggestions to get the desired output, as i don't know why i get so many records since i am only doing inner joins.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code & desired output & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) That includes a clear specification--a description of how the result you want is a function of the input. But you do not give one. We only have an example so we can only guess what that is. And this is not *minimal*. PS Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: "That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)" So are Rep & RMA both correct? "That includes a clear specification--a description of how the result you want is a function of the input. But you do not give one." Well? (When describing a result: Say enough that someone could go away & come back with a solution.) "i am only using inner joins there should't be that many"--not helpful. INNER JOIN does a cross join & keeps the rews that make the ON true. So what is the actual condition for rows you want?

Comment: Google 'stackexchange notifications' to learn to use @x to notify one non-poster non-sole commenter x about a comment. PS Please use standard grammar & punctuation.

Comment: There's no special join and this is not a technical issue. You need to specify why the very first row in your example output only gets `rma_id=1` but not 2 or 3. AFAIK these are valid joins and you will have to explicitly throw away data.

Comment: You've done really well to generate a MCVE, but the column names and order in the MCVE need to match your required output. Otherwise it's far too confusing to work it out. There is definitely an answer here but again it's not a technical issue, it's a business logic issue

Comment: Hi @Nick.McDermaid, yes, the first issue is that one inner join was not OK, the first two joins of each table with device, worked as i expected, the second join of report with report-replacement wasn't it was just the order of the fields in the that inner join on clause. 

i am now stuck with the issue of  eliminating the rows that combine all the records of reportid with all the records of rma id 1, as i need them to be a 1 to 1 relation.

I know didn't make my case clear  i am trying to comply with every request/sugestion for posting guidelines, but my question is not a trouble shoothing

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, its a question about sql lenguaje in general on how to program the logic necesary to get the desired output,  maybe using case clauses, maybe with cte, i am not very versed in sql i am still learning my knowledge in sql is very limited, not like a dba would be.

Comment: @philipxy, thanks for your hints, i am trying to comply with anything that would help my question. I apologize for the shortcomings in english and sql jargon, not my natural lenguaje nor very experienced in this field. –

Comment: You’re doing excellent.  I need to go offline but the short answer is: use group by to pre-summarise tables before joining so you can ensure joins are 1-1. For example the SQL inside the brackets that you have aliased as RMA can be rewritten with group by or distinct to ensure it yields a unique join column. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: You are not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. Does the subquery for Rep return the right value when run on its own, or not? Does the subquery for RMA return the right value when run on its own, or not? To debug, select * for a join until you know it is correct. "RMA and Reps are both ok when joining with the device detail table" doesn't make sense, they are the output of joins with it. Please clarify via edits, not comments. Edit to be the best presentation right now. (But don't invalidate reasonable answer posts.)

Comment: If you could align the columns in your MCVE with your requirements I can take another look

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, solved it.  I used 
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY replacement.id ORDER BY replacement.id) AS seq that to modify the join conditions.

thanks for your time. :) i owe you a beer

Comment: I'm pleased you solved it.

Comment: Please consider posting  an answer to your question & editing the question to be just the question. You can accept it after minimum wait. This helps others who find your question know that you found a satisfactory answer. PS I still can't follow you. You say "the inner join of table reports with table [report-replacement]" but you don't join those tables, you join table [report-replacement] with the result of joining reports & device. Also: You don't say what your query should do. These are not problems with English or SQL. The problem is not enough effort & practice to think & write clearly.

Comment: PS Here is how to give "a clear specification--a description of how the result you want is a function of the input": Finish/fix this sentence: "a row of values (report_id, ...) is in the result when/iff a row (rep.ID,....) is in report & ... & rep.ID=report_id & ... & ... & a row of values (ID,...) is in Rep when/iff a row (report.ID,...) is in report & ... & report.ID=ID & ...".

Comment: @philipxy, i am a complete noob to this site, i don't know how to do what you ask me to do, i don't know how to post an answer to my question, but with your guidance i am happy to edit, or post anything that will help others to deal with this same problem.  

I am a noob in SQL (not programming )  but the main issue of this hole post was that, as i understand inner joins, this was an "unexpected dificulty".

Comment: Google "stackoverflow how to post an answer to my question" & "stackoverflow how do i accept an answer". If you don't know what to do re comments then ask for clarification--as you do. PS People who write "as I understand" seem to think that they don't understand & they write as if they don't understand. Find a definition in a published textbook or DBMS manual & do not rest until you believe you understand. PS Most of my comments have been that you are not clear. I expect that you think that you're likely unclear & that you hope that you're clear enough. "enough effort & practice".

Answer (score 2):

This is the solution to my question.

```
select 
rep.ID as report_id,
rep.itemID as reported_item,
rep.dev_detail as reported_item_detail,
rep.replaceID as report_replace_id,
rma.id as rma_id,
rma.ItemID as rma_item,
rma.dev_detail as rma_item_detail,
Rep.seq,
rma.seq
from
(
  select report.ID,report.itemID,device.dev_detail, [report-replacement].replaceID,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY report.id ORDER BY report.id) AS seq
  from 
   report 
    inner join device on device.ID = Report.ID
    inner join [report-replacement] on [report-replacement].reportID = Report.ID
) as Rep
inner join
(
  select
  replacement.id,replacement.ItemID,device.dev_detail,
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY replacement.id ORDER BY replacement.id) AS seq
  from 
  replacement 
  inner join device on device.ID = replacement.ItemID
) as RMA
on rep.replaceID = RMA.id AND rep.seq=rma.seq
```

The problem is commonly called cross-join by proxy.

Solution seems to be based on the use of ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY replacement.id ORDER BY replacement.id) AS seq